# How do I "background mine" on CLI for Helium Hydra v.0.11.0.0?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, helium-hydra

I've looked under 'help' in my daemon and wallet and found nothing that seems to describe how to background mine.  Is that only a function in the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background mining is done by adding "true" at the end of the start_mining command in monero-wallet-cli, after the number of threads. This means the number of threads is not optionalk in that case:

start_mining 4 true

This will start background mining on 4 threads.

Answer (score 0):

https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/monero-wallet-cli.html

If you want to mine, you can do so from the wallet:

```
start_mining 2
```

Comment: I understand that... but what I'm talking about is the ability to "background mine" which is a new thing (at least what I've seen in the GUI) that allows to throttles your computer in a way from not overheating.